# Concatenating multiple files into one

Tags: c++, file, concatenation

Okay, so I want to concatenate multiple files into one. The problem is that the final file is empty. I want to know how I can write stuff into a file without overwriting and so on. Here's my code.
Thanks in advance!

```
    void concatenate()
{
    fstream fileToConcatenate, result;
    unsigned numberOfFiles = 0;
    char fileName[MAX], finalFileName[MAX];
    puts("Please tell me how many files you want to concatenate.");
    cin >> numberOfFiles;
    puts("Please tell me data for the resulted file.\n*Hint: full path followed by the file name.\n*E.g:C:\\Users\\IoanaAlexandra\\test.txt");
    cin >> finalFileName;
    result.open(finalFileName, ios::out|ios::ate);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 0:puts("Please tell me the file data for the first file to be concatenated.\n*Hint: full path followed by the file name.\n*E.g:C:\\Users\\IoanaAlexandra\\test.txt"); break;
            case 1:puts("Please tell me the file data for the second file."); break;
            case 2:puts("Please tell me the file data for the third file."); break;
            default:cout << "Please tell me the file data for the " << i << "th file."; break;
            }
            cin >> fileName;
            fileToConcatenate.open(fileName, ios::in);
            if (result.is_open())
            {
                if (fileToConcatenate.is_open())
                {
                    result << fileToConcatenate.rdbuf();
                }
                else
                {
                    puts("The file you are trying to concatenate from doesn't exist!Try again!");
                    concatenate();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                puts("The result file could not be created! Try again!");
                concatenate();
            }
        }
    fileToConcatenate.close();
    result.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite know how to do that xd.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You were editing.  No worries

Comment: Shouldn't you close `fileToConcatenate` before calling `concatenate()` again in the loop?

Comment: What is the output of your program?

Comment: Just the content of the first file.

Comment: calling the function recursively is a very bad idea here... you should close the files before calling, and insert a return statement after.

Comment: @user3105558 you get the content of the first file in the output? Not in the file?

Comment: @user3105558 - You are checking if the file is successfuly opened, if it's you should close it before calling `concatenate()` again.

Comment: Oh, the output is clean. In the result file there's only the content of the 1st file.

Comment: @user3105558 - Because the first time you open the file, you don't close it, so the other files can't be written, that's my guess.

Comment: Let me try to close them and run some tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `result.open()` from the outside of the loop and try changing your code to something like:

```
 fileToConcatenate.open(fileName, ios::in);
 if (fileToConcatenate.is_open())
 {
      // open output file
      result.open(finalFileName, ios::out|ios::ate);
      // you should check so the output file really was opened correctly here
      result << fileToConcatenate.rdbuf();
      // close the input file
      fileToConcatenate.close();
      // close output file
      result.close();
 }
 else
 {
      puts("The file you are trying to concatenate from doesn't exist!Try again!");
      concatenate();
 }
```

You should also close the `fileToConcatenate` if it was opened before calling `concatenate()` again.